# Android application not working on all versions

Tags: android

I have just worked on my first Android application and introduced it in Google Play. But the application is not working on some Android versions. I tried it on Sony Xperia with Android 2.3.7 it did not downloaded.

But when I tried it on another Sony Xperia phone which was having Android 2.3.6 it downloaded and worked perfectly. I am confused by why it is not working on all of Android versions.

### Update

I am sorry last time I mentioned wrong version.

Comment: Are you shure that this isn't a problem of the first phone itself? I't could be possible that it wouldn't run on 4.0+ but 2.6.6 and 2.6.7... that's not that big of a difference#

Comment: Are you sure about the version? there is no android 2.6 version.

Comment: could that be the linux kernel version on which it's based?

Comment: i am sorry about version I have corrected it now. Please check it again

Comment: What do you mean with 'it did not downloaded'?